# looking for specific mac address in switch

Tags: cisco-ios

I use Packet Tracer 6.0.1 to implement a lab and I trying to find command to look for a specific mac address in a switch.

I already tried all these and no succeed

**‪#‎show‬ mac address-table address 0254.008c.259e**

**‪#‎show‬ mac address-table address | include 0254.008c.259e**

**‪#‎sh‬ mac-address-table | include 0254.008c.259e**

**#sh mac add dy | inc 259e**

**#sh mac add dy | inc .259e**

Nay help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sh mac add dy" is not correct. First: If it's IOS, it's show mac address-table | inc  <--- that should work

If it's CatOS, it's "show cam dynamic" .

If you're not seeing the mac, it's probably not there. Forget looking for the specific mac and just do a show mac address-table and see if it shows any entries. You can show mac address on specific ports if you know which port it's plugged in to. Just hit ? after typing show mac address-table .